# Release apk wont open w/ firebase installed in react native

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I started creating apk file w/ command

> "./gradlew assembleRelease"

But when i install the apk on the android phone, the app install failed and it won't open.

Upon investigating the logs and history of my work. I think react-native-firebase is the problem here but I don't know how to fix it.

before I installed react-native-firebase the app release is working as always but
after that the app won't open

**Note:** I only implement Firebase Notification and Cloud Messaging.

It works in debug mode but not in release.

Edit:
For my further investigation. when I comment out this line with RNfirebase dependencies, the app release work again

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.sdg.projectdave">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>




<!-- comment out all firebase related and the app will work -->
    <application>

    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
     <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseInstanceIdService">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
  </service>
    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" />

    <receiver android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseBackgroundNotificationActionReceiver" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.BackgroundAction"/>
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseBackgroundNotificationActionsService"/>
    </application>

    <application>
  <receiver android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationReceiver"/>
  <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"  android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsRebootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
      <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  </application>


    <application>

    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
      android:resource="@drawable/launch_screen" />

    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
      android:resource="@color/blueish" />

     <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
    android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
    </application>



    <!-- data only -->

    <!-- <application ...>
       <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" />
    </application> -->


</manifest>
```

Comment: Dont post text as image

Comment: ok sir. i deleted it because it is unecessary . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue. the problem is that i declared multiple application tag wrapper `"<application>"` inside AndroidManifest. it should only used once.

i modify my code like this:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.sdg.projectdave">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

    <application>

    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
     <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseInstanceIdService">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
  </service>
    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" />

    <receiver android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseBackgroundNotificationActionReceiver" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.BackgroundAction"/>
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseBackgroundNotificationActionsService"/>
    </application>

    <application>
  <receiver android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationReceiver"/>
  <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"  android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsRebootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
      <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  </application>


    <application>

    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
      android:resource="@drawable/launch_screen" />

    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
      android:resource="@color/blueish" />

     <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
    android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
    </application>



    <!-- data only -->

    <!-- <application ...>
       <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" />
    </application> -->


</manifest>
```

This made me confused, because it works on debug mode but for some reason in release build it wont install. w/ multiple `<application>` tag.